# What hardware and OS should I use for my home router/server setup for good filesharing capabilities?

Tags: backup, router, file-sharing, nat

I would like to set up a new server at home that should be able to perform the following tasks:

- Act as firewall/router/NAT for my home network
- Share lots of files, mostley music
- Misc. other stuff, webhosting etc.

I've previously used a FreeBSD box but it's running old and the hardware is failing. I would like to have a system with at least ~2TB of storage with appropriate redundancy/backup mechanisms (RAID, ...) in place. The only requirement I have is that it should be able to route the internet traffic (100mbit) without effort and I'd like the local network to be 1Gbit.

- Which OS is a good choice?
- What's a good solution for the storage?
- What's the minimum amount off memory needed?
- What else should I think about?
- Are there any good resources for info on the subject?

Comment: In my honest opinion this question should be on both as it is valid on both sites and could get better coverage.

Comment: Diago, it's an edge case for SF. I'm sitting on the fence - but I won't reopen it for now I think that it's a common question more for home users than for IT professionals (music sharing...). Also, there is a link to this question here, so I hope users who know a good ansers will switch to SU.

Answer (score 1):

pfSense is a FreeBSD based firewall/router/everything and has a web interface. I'm not sure if this is the distro that you're using now, but if it's not it's worth a look. You really should be weary of hosting a file server on an edge device, it's a little scary, but if you're not concerned about security then go for it.

Comment: Seconded on misgivings about the edge device being a file server. I wouldn't do it that way. I'd recommend 2 separate boxes.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [ClarkConnect](http://www.clarkconnect.com/), a CentOS 5 based distro with every conceivable local server feature, from Bandwidth Management to Mail Quarantine and VPN.

- Firewall, Networking and Security
- VPN / Virtual Private Networks
- Web Proxy and Filtering
- E-mail
- Groupware
- File and Print Services
- Database and Web Server

[Requirements here](http://www.clarkconnect.com/info/requirements.php), 512MB RAM recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I think FreeBSD is a very good choice, because it has excellent network performance and good storage capabilities, especially with newly added ZFS. 
You can use as skeleton either [pfSense](http://www.pfsense.com/) (easy to manage router) or [FreeNAS](http://www.freenas.org/) (easy to manage router). Or if you don't need any kind of Web interface, just setup custom server-router using [iso of upcoming FreeBSD 8.0 release](ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/ISO-IMAGES-amd64/8.0/)